# Why is one variable undefined outside of the IIFE while the other is not?

Tags: javascript, scope, iife

I was playing with IIFE and I'm confused. The value of `a` is `undefined` but `b` is not. Why am I able to access the value of `b` outside of IIFE?

```js
(function(){
  var a = b = 3;
})();

console.log("a defined? " + (typeof a !== 'undefined')); // false
console.log("b defined? " + (typeof b !== 'undefined')); // true
```

Comment: `b` is an implicit global because it has not been declared.

Comment: Should be `var a = 3, b = a;`

Comment: …or `var a, b; a = b = 3;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declaration syntax can be confusing, because it *looks* like the syntax for ordinary expressions. It is, however, different.

```
var a = b = 3;
```

is parsed as

```
var a = (something);
```

In this case, `something` is `b = 3`, so it's exactly as if your function looked like

```
b = 3;
var a = b;
```

The "naked" `b = 3` without `var` or `let` or `const` creates an *implicit global variable*. Thus `b` is visible outside the function, while `a` is not.

Answer (score 7):

There are four ways of declaring a variable in JavaScript:

- `var`, which will scope that variable to the declaring function.
- `let`/`const`, which will scope that variable to the declaring block.
- Implicit declaration, which will scope that variable globally (unless previously declared in a different scope, in which case it will reassign that instead).

```
var a = b = 3;
```

In this statement, we declare `a` in the function scope with the value of `b = 3`. The expression `b = 3` has value 3, but implicitly declares the variable `b` as well, which means that `b` will be declared in the global scope.

Outside of the function, the variable `b` is declared (since it was implicitly declared globally) while `a` is not (since it was declared only in the scope of the function).

---

You should avoid implicitly declared variables, though  (and preferably use `let` and `const` instead of `var`), so the above code should have been written like this:

```
(function() {
  let a = 3;
  let b = a;
});
```

Or, if you actually want the variables declared outside of the function as well:

```
let a, b;
(function() {
  // NOTE: not implicit declaration since a and b are both already declared
  a = 3;
  b = a;
})();
```